# How to replace characters using a for loop?

Tags: for-loop

The problem I have been having is that the for loop does not check the whole word. instead it only checks it at the index provided.I need it to be able to check any word for any instances of those letters and replace them with its corresponding symbol. How would I check the whole word for the letter I am looking to change. This is what I have been able to get so far:

```
 cout << "Enter word: ";
   cin >> userInput;
   cout << "You entered: " ;
   cin >> userInput;

   for (unsigned i=0; userInput.size() > i; i++){
      if (userInput.at(0)=='a'){
        userInput.at(0)=='@';
      }
      if (userInput.at(1)=='e'){
        userInput.at(1)=='3';
      }
      if (userInput.at(2)=='i'){
        userInput.at(2)=='!';
      }
       if (userInput.at(3)=='g'){
         userInput.at(3)=='9';
      }
       if (userInput.at(4)=='s'){
         userInput.at(4)=='$';
      }
       if (userInput.at(5)=='x'){
     userInput.at(5)=='*';
      }

   }
   cout << "New word: ";
   cout << userInput;
```

Comment: What is "the index provided?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to replace all 'a' with '@', and so on.  As the code is written, it will only ever consider the first character for the a -> @ replacement, the second character with the e -> 3 replacement, etc.

A couple quick things.  Using `==` tests for equality.  You do want to test for equality initially, but you later also want to perform an assignment (`=`).

Second, you probably want to look character-by-character.  Test each character against the values you want to replace.  The value at `userInput.at(i)` is the character for that iteration of the loop.

```
   for (unsigned i=0; userInput.size() > i; i++) {
      // Note, we're indexing based on the variable i, 
      // instead of a hard-coded number value
      if (userInput.at(i) == 'a') {

        // Note the single = on the line below
        userInput.at(i) = '@';
      }

      if (userInput.at(i) == 'e') {
        userInput.at(i) = '3';
      }

      // and so on
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it now.